# Ways to reference an icon in an android app

Tags: java, android, icons

I know you can reference an icon with

```
<item   android:id="@+id/config"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_config"
    android:title="@string/config"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

So this goes in the drawable folder and looks up the ic_config image.
But I recently saw this:

```
    android:id="@+id/config"
    android:icon="?iconConfig"
    android:title="@string/config"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Now I don't understand how the mapping between my config-image and `?iconConfig` is working, I can see that '**iconConfig**' appears in the R.java and attr.xml files, but nowhere else.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039310/difference-between-androidicon-drawable-my-icon-and-androidicon-my-icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the following link:

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

**Edit**

for your convenience i am posting the required part from link provided above:

> Just like styles, themes are also declared in XML  elements,
>   and are referenced in the same manner. The difference is that you add
>   a theme to an entire application or activity, via the 
>   and  elements in the Android Manifest — themes cannot be
>   applied to individual Views.
>
> Here's an example declaration of a theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>   <style name="CustomTheme">        
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowFrame">@drawable/screen_frame</item>
    <item name="windowBackground">@drawable/screen_background_white</item>
    <item name="panelForegroundColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="panelBackgroundColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="panelTextColor">?panelForegroundColor</item>
    <item name="panelTextSize">14</item>
    <item name="menuItemTextColor">?panelTextColor</item>
    <item name="menuItemTextSize">?panelTextSize</item>   </style> </resources>
```

> Notice the use of the at-symbol (@) and the question-mark (?) to
>   reference resources. The at-symbol indicates that we're referencing a
>   resource previously defined elsewhere (which may be from this project
>   or from the Android framework). The question-mark indicates that we're
>   referencing a resource value in the currently loaded theme. This is
>   done by referring to a specific  by its name value. (E.g.,
>   panelTextColor uses the same color assigned to panelForegroundColor,
>   defined beforehand.) This technique can be used only in XML resources.

Comment: I see, but still in which file is it listed that if I reference iconConfig it is taking the ic_config image? I don't understand the mapping yet.

Comment: @user2870415 plz check my edit ...hope it'll help you now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'?' is used when you need to refer to the drawable while having several themes. It is made to simplify the logic when switching between themes and let the Android automatically decide which resource to use.